# Re-using recent outlook search

Tags: search, microsoft-outlook-2013

Is it possible to save/use recent outlook search item?
I do not want to create search folders. Rather I want to use recent search strings.
for example if I recently used the search string in the search bar

```
from:me to:others categories:(IMP AND TODO)
where IMP and TODO are categories I have created
```

Can I quickly use the search string; something like a history of recently used search strings.
I do understand that there is a "Recent Searches" option in search ribbon. I am interested to see this option right from the search box itself. I think this used to be in earlier outlook versions.

```
System Info:
Microsoft Outlook, Microsoft Office Professional Plau 2013
Windows 8.1
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do it right in the search box. The only way is to use the "Recent Searches" button.